# Trying to redirect to full-site homepage onclick

Tags: javascript, drupal

I am working on a drupal website that has a mobile site and a desktop site. When in the mobile site, there is a "Full Site" button that should redirect the user back to the homepage of the desktop site. Since I need to set a cookie when that button is clicked, the "href" is left blank and the onclick goes to a function. However, when setting the "location.replace" in the function to the base url, I still get redirected to the existing page. Any thoughts as to how I can fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

ex:
current page = mysite.com/news-mobile

desired page redirect = mysite.com

actual page redirect = mypage.com/news-mobile

NOTE: This is a staging site so there is no "www"

html:

```
<div class="one_third">
    <a class="buttonWrapper buttonBlue" href="" onclick=goToMobile()>Full Site</a>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function goToMobile(){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = "ismobile = false" + expires;
    document.location.replace('http://mypage.com');
}
```

EDIT:

I updated the html for the button to open in a new tab. This causes the original tab to refresh with the homepage, but the new tab still loads the desktop-version of that specific mobile-page. (i.e. window 1 opens desktop-home and window 2 opens desktop-mobil_email :doesn't exist). Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

New html:

```
<div class="one_third">
        <a class="buttonWrapper buttonBlue" target="_blank" href="#" onclick=goToMobile()>Full Site</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have solved this issue by changing the href tag to say `href='#'`

Comment: I was going to tell you that but I couldn't try it since I don't have the complete code to test it :(